# Disable or Remove 'Create Account' option from one drive authentication page

Tags: ios, onedrive

I am trying to integrate onedrive for my ios app. I am using onedrive ios sdk for that. I am calling ODClient.authenticatedClientWithCompletion for launching authentication screen. This does launch authentication screen, and I am able to login. However in the authentication screen, both Sign In and 'No Account? Create One' option is visible. According to apple guideline an app will be rejected, if its integration point has create account option, as its violates their policy. This is the reason why dropbox, google drive sdk's for ios, does not have create account option. Is there a way by which I can disable or remove 'Create Account' option from one drive authentication screen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Apple policies has been changed. My app was approved even though, even though one drive's create account option coming.

Comment: Could you provide a link to any documentation to back this up? It may well be useful for others.